# Script not found from custom menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I attempt to run a function through a custom menu on a spreadsheet I'm getting the following error:

```
[19-08-30 06:28:30:884 PDT] Starting execution
[19-08-30 06:28:30:954 PDT] Execution failed: Script function not found: 
function newUserSetup() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("Evaluations");
    testProperties = {"email":"XXX", 
"webhook":"XXX", "api_token":"XXX"};
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperties(testProperties);
    collectAndCompare();
    log("ran testSetup with no problems ");
}
```

It's saying it cannot find the function, but it's listing all the function's contents.

I've tried:

- Testing this as an add on
- Looking at the execution
- Running a different function from the custom menu
- Updating from `Publish` -> `Publish as Web App`, new version

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Evals')
  .addItem('Setup', 'newUserSetup')
  .addItem('TestSetup', 'testUserSetup')
  // .addSeperator()
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Reset')
              .addItem('Webhook', 'resetWebhook')
              .addItem('Token', 'resetToken')
              .addItem('Email', 'resetEmail')
              .addItem('Reset All', 'resetAll'))
  .addToUi();
}
```

Previously, I've been able to select a custom menu from the sheet and have it run. Unsure where to look next because I would try using the logger, but since it's not entering that first function I don't know where to log anything.

Comment: *It's saying it cannot find the function, but it's listing all the function's contents.* Only reason that could happen is if you provided the function instead of function name as a string. Did you miss the quotes`"newUserSetup"`?

Comment: Hm, that didn't seem to make any difference in the behavior for me.

Comment: I'm saying : though you have quotes here, you might have missed it in the actual script: `addItem('Setup', 'newUserSetup')`. `newUserSetup` should be quoted.

Comment: Does the error message also say `For more information, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String)`? This would be another indication that you misspelled the function call.